# UPDATE запрос для комментирования закрывающихся попарно в ноль позиций

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть одна таблица с данными со столбцами Организация, БухСчет, Дата документа, СуммаРуб и Комментарий.

Часть позиций этой таблицы закрываются попарно по столбцу СуммаРуб в ноль(плюс на минус), при этом по этим позициям (попарно закрывающимся в ноль) значения Организация, БухСчет, Дата документа - обязательно должны быть равны между в рамках обеих позиций. Необходимо по всем таким закрывающимся в ноль позициям проставить общий комментарий = "закрывается в ноль"

Comment: вам, видимо, на сайты фрилансеров надо обратиться.

Comment: Ну самый же вульгарный multiple-table UPDATE, использующий две копии указанной таблицы.